# FlexBox сужает фиксированные блоки

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7xk2hzm/4/)

Как сделать так что-бы блоки не сужались, а выходили за пределы блока родителя?

```css
body {
  background: #20262e;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

@keyframes slidan {
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

body>div {
  background: #2a313c;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: 4s slidan infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.76, 0.1, 0.5, 0.99);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div>div {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #323c4a;
}

div>div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Для этого во `flex-box` существует параметр `flex` c 3 аргументами:

1. `flex-grow` - коэффициент растягивания
2. `flex-shrink` - коэффициент сжатия
3. `flex-basis` - базовая величина элемента относительно которого происходит растягивание-сжатие

Вам необходимо указать следующее:

```
div > div {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #323c4a;
  flex: 0 0 48px; //тут задается поведение сжатия-растягивания относительно flex-basis
}
```

[Шпаргалка по flex-box](https://habr.com/ru/post/431014/)

Возможно, ещё придётся убрать `overflow: hidden`, если хотите чтобы отображалось как блоки перекрывают область родителя.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, есть вариант задать минимальную ширину блока, выглядеть будет вот так.

```
div > div {
  min-width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #323c4a;
}
```

`min-width` - минимальная ширина.

Надеюсь вам это помогло.